# Por que me sale que no es una funcion? en node js con express

Tags: nodejs, express, backend, encriptación, passport

Hola estoy intentando hacer que mi aplicación inicie sesión, pero no logro hacer debido a un error, no he podido resolverlo y necesito ayuda.

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');
const bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
        type: String,
        require: true,
    },
    email : {
         type: String,
         require: true,
         unique: true
    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

UserSchema.methods.encryptPassword = async (password) =>{
   const salt = await bcryptjs.genSalt(10);
   return await bcryptjs.hash(password, salt);
};

UserSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function(password){
    return await bcryptjs.compare(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = model('users', UserSchema);
```

este es el esquema que estoy utilizando y utilizo un modulo para encriptar las contraseñas y compararlas al iniciar sesion.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');

passport.use(new localStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, async (email, password, done) => {

    // Match Email´s User
    const user = await User.findOne({email: email});
    if(!user) { 
       return done(null, false, {menssage: 'Not User Found'}); 
    }else{
        // Match Password's User
        const match = await User.matchPassword(password);
        if(match){
            return done(null, user);
        }else{
            return done(null, false, {menssage: 'Incorrect Password'});
        }
    }
}));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) =>{
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

en esta parte estoy llamando a la función `macthPassword` pero me manda el siguiente mensaje de error cuando intento iniciar sesión en la aplicación.

```
(node:8160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: User.matchPassword is not a function
    at Strategy._verify (C:\Users\Johan Semprum\Desktop\FAZT NODEJS\src\config\passport.js:16:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:8160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

Sinceramente no se que pueda ser pero necesito ayuda, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería demasiado, muchas gracias de antemano, quedo atento a cualquier pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que no lo estas usando correctamente, en el siguiente trozo de código:

```
const match = await User.matchPassword(password);
```

Estás usando el modelo directamente y no la variable `user` con el objeto que te devuelve al usar el modelo.

Si no me equivoco, deberia de ser de la siguiente forma:

```
const match = await user.matchPassword(password);
```

Ahora deberias de poder usar el método **matchPassword**.